# How to define codeception environment variable in laravel-4 form .env.codecept.php

Tags: php, laravel-4, codeception

I am trying to implement codeception on my laravel 4 project. I am very new with codeception.

I have created `.env.codecept.php` file to store environment variable for testing in codeception. But I don't now how to get these variable in `codeception.yml`.

Please guide how to implement this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's already shown in their [official guide](https://codeception.com/for/laravel), in the .yml:

```
config:
        - Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.codecept
```